# What sports a 30-year-old male can pursue other than endurance sports?

Tags: sports

I am  30-year-old healthy male working in academics from India. Right now working as a researcher and hopefully would be working as an assistant professor very soon. I am a regular gym goer. I have this burning desire in me to excel at some physical activity for a very long time. But could not pursue due to various reasons.

I am very much interested in pursuing a parallel career as an amateur athlete with the hopes of becoming pro one day. Please also explain my possibilities in Girevoy. Options other than endurance sports are also welcome

Is this very late? If not what sports are feasible for me? please suggest using these parameters (but not limited to):

1. **The Probability of participation in competitions.**
2. The time and monetary costs.
3. The facilities required.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: triathlon :-). Start with easy pace and there you go. You are an ironman. That is how I start running triathlon and I am an academic staff too.

Comment: @bantandor thanks. how did you prepared for the triathlon while working.

Comment: http://www.beginnertriathlete.com/  this is a great site to start with

Comment: This is a very personal question and the possibilities are almost endless, from marathons to strongman competitions to time trial cycling or fell running.

Answer (score 6):

At that age, men lose speed but gain endurance. If you look at cycling tours or marathons, most of the guys are over 30. So you should focus on any sport where endurance is more important that strength/speed if you want to train for competition and actually have a chance. So march, marathon and route cycling. Running is cheap. High quality shoes can cost you like 100$+. You may get a hearth rate monitor and gps. For cycling, you have to get a bike capable of competing and that can cost up to 1000$ minimum. That would be like a mid range road bike. You would need some thing with at least shimano 105 group and carbon fork.

All this needs a few times per week training, and, as you are training endurance it will take few hours per session.

You only need a road for a bike and a ground for you foot to run/walk.

You can also practice some unpopular sports. Where the small number of people bring bigger chances to people who take them seriously.

Comment: nicely and well said :)

Answer (score 2):

I could give you a real life example of my brother that is a 35 year old male and did go to the gym regular but didn't push it hard just did it to make some movement as he is held at a desk 8 hours daily.

Now he is jogging and cycling for like a year and has started to get really decent results running over 25 km a day and cycling over 45 km per day(note:he doesn't jog the same day he cycles) .You just need to be motivated and have 1 hour per day after work to spend for training.

He said it's a lot better to run than go to a gym cause it took him like 30 minutes only to get there in the traffic as for running ,you get out and...start running.